# Power parameters for VMware in MaaS CLI

Tags: command-line, juju, maas

I am playing with MaaS in a vSphere environment so I can simulate large clusters. I have finished my auto-provisioning PowerShell script, where I can provision a bunch of virtual machines to be added to the MaaS controller. I can add these nodes manually in the Controller GUI and I was able to commission them accordingly. I'm currently trying to figure out how to add the machines via the MaaS CLI, and I'm stuck on the `power_parameters` parameter. Based off the [MaaS API documentation](https://docs.maas.io/2.5/en/api), I have to add everything as a `key=value` type.

Where I'm stuck is on how to add that parameter in the CLI. If I don't pass `power_parameters`, I get this error:

```bsh
400 BAD REQUEST

       Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
               Date: Mon, 25 Mar 2019 21:01:03 GMT
             Server: TwistedWeb/16.0.0
             Status: 400
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
               Vary: Cookie
    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

{"power_parameters": ["This field is required."]}
```

But I cannot figure out the proper string formatting for the parameter. I have tried several combos:

```bsh
# tried adding it as a string as the docs say
maas <user> machines create -d \
  ... \
  power_parameters="power_vm_name=<vmname> power_uuid=<vmuuid>"

# tried query string separating
maas <user> machines create -d \
  ... \
  power_parameters="power_vm_name=<vmname>&power_uuid=<vmuuid>"

# tried comma separating
maas <user> machines create -d \
  ... \
  power_parameters=power_vm_name=<vmname>,power_uuid=<vmuuid>

# tried individual parameters
maas <user> machines create -d \
  ... \
  power_vm_name=<vmname> power_uuid=<vmuuid>
```

I get this error with every permutation I've tried:

```
400 BAD REQUEST

       Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
               Date: Mon, 25 Mar 2019 20:54:24 GMT
             Server: TwistedWeb/16.0.0
             Status: 400
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
               Vary: Cookie
    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

Failed to parse JSON power_parameters
```

I know I can send the raw JSON payload via REST, but I don't really want to implement a REST client in PowerShell for MaaS.

What is the proper string formatting for adding `power_parameters` in the MaaS CLI?

Answer (score 1):

So, I ripped apart the MaaS CLI code base, and I saw lots of references to `power_parameters_<param>` in the code base, which led me to believe it's looking for a specific key formatting.

This is what ended up working for me:

```bsh
maas <user> machines create -d \\
    architecture=amd64 \
    mac_addresses=<mac> \
    domain=<domain> \
    hostname=<name> \
    power_type=vmware \
    power_parameters_power_vm_name=<vm_name> \
    power_parameters_power_uuid=<vm_uuid> \
    power_parameters_power_address=<vcenter_host_name> \
    power_parameters_power_user='<maas_user_in_quotes>' \
    power_parameters_power_pass='<password_in_quotes>' \
    power_parameters_power_port=443 \
    power_parameters_power_protocol=https+unverified
```

I was then able to see the machine in the Controller UI.